# How to retrieve specific row's data from database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, row

I am working on a project and stuck at a point. I have designed a form which insert a person's profile detail in database.... now I want that as the person submit the entries into database the next page after submission should be the preview of the entered profile like the person's image name and other details.

**This is my controller code**

```
public function listbusiness()
{
    $this->load->model('client/Client_model');
    $this->Client_model->checksession();
    if($this->input->post("continue",TRUE)){


        $ptype = $this->input->post('ptype');
        $ftype = $this->input->post('ftype');

        $peckage=array();
        if($this->input->post('pktype1'))
        {
            $pk1=$this->input->post('pktype1');
            $price1=$this->input->post('price1');
            $peckage[$pk1]=$price1;
        }
        if($this->input->post('pktype2'))
        {
            $pk2=$this->input->post('pktype2');
            $price2=$this->input->post('price2');
            $peckage[$pk2]=$price2;
        }
        if($this->input->post('pktype3'))
        {
            $pk3=$this->input->post('pktype3');
            $price3=$this->input->post('price3');
            $peckage[$pk3]=$price3;
        }
        if($this->input->post('pktype4'))
        {
            $pk4=$this->input->post('pktype4');
            $price4=$this->input->post('price4');
            $peckage[$pk4]=$price4;
        }
        $sessiondata=array('ptype'=>$ptype,'ftype'=>$ftype,'pkage'=>$peckage);

        $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);

        $city = $this->input->post('City');
        $this->session->set_userdata('city',$city);

    }
    if($this->input->post("submit",TRUE)){

        //print_r($_POST);die;

        //print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        //die;

        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $desc = $this->input->post('desc');
        $term = $this->input->post('term');
        //$file = $this->input->files('files');
        $add = $this->input->post('add');
        //$name = $this->input->post('stud_name');


        $bid = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        //$file=str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES['stud_img']['name']);
        $pp=implode($this->session->userdata('ptype'));
        $ff=implode($this->session->userdata('ftype'));
        $newdata=array("name"=>$title,
                       "detail"=>$desc,
                       "type"=>$pp,
                       "address"=>$add,
                       //"price"=>$price,
                       "facility"=>$ff,
                       "city"=>$this->session->userdata('city'),
                       "bussid"=>$bid['userid']);

                        //print_r($newdata);die;

        $retval=$this->Client_model->save("listing",$newdata);

        if($retval>0)
        {
            //print_r($newdata);die;
            $apack=$this->session->userdata('pkage');
            foreach($apack as $key=>$value)
            {
                $price=array("packtype"=>$key,"price"=>$value,'lid'=>$retval);
                if($value!='')
                {
                    $this->Client_model->save("price",$price);
                }
            }
            if(isset($_FILES['files']))
            {
                $photoname=$_FILES['files']['name'];
                $photopath=$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];    
                $name=implode(",",$photoname);
                $uploaddata=array("name"=>str_replace(" ","_",$name),"lid"=>$retval);
                $retval1=$this->Client_model->saveupload("photo",$uploaddata);                   
                if($retval1>0)
                {
                    $size=count($photoname);
                    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
                    {

                        $filename=str_replace(" ","_",$photoname[$i]);
                        move_uploaded_file($photopath[$i],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/clubhouz/upload/photo/".$filename);
                    }
                }
            }
            //redirect("business/businessdetail");
            //$insertid=base64_encode($value['id']);
            // $insertid = $this->db->insert_id();
            $insertid=base64_encode($value['id']);
            redirect('viewlistdetail?id=$newid'); 

        }

    }
```

This is in the model:

```
function viewlistdetail($st)
{
    //echo $st;die;
    $data['page_title'] = 'List View';
    $data['detail']=$this->getlistdetail($st);

    $this->load->view('client/general/head',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/general/header');
    $this->load->view('client/listview',$data);
    $this->load->view('client/general/footer');
}
```

and the listview displays the last inserted record,
but there is error of **page not found** after I submit the form.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: please review my this code

Comment: This might be a bad practice. Don't load views in a model. Do it on a controller.

Comment: not working still there is an page not found error

Comment: this error is resolved but now when the page is redirected to the viewdetails page it is showing this error:
A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

SEVERITY: WARNING

MESSAGE: ILLEGAL STRING OFFSET 'NAME'

FILENAME: CLIENT/LISTVIEW.PHP

LINE NUMBER: 7

Comment: show the code of listview.php

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following procedure and apply it in your project.

your `controller` file, I assume, its file name is persons.php

```
class Persons extends CI_Controller {
  function view($id)
  {
    $this->load->model(array('Persons_model'));

    $person     = $this->Person_model->get_person($id);
    $data['first_name'] = $person->first_name;
    $data['last_name'] = $person->last_name;
    $this->load->view('person_view', $data);
  }
}
```

your `model` file, I assume, its file name is persons_model.php

```
Class Persons_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_person($id)
    {

        $result = $this->db->get_where('persons', array('id'=>$id));
        return $result->row();
    }
{
```

your `view` file, I assume, its file name is person_view.php

```
<div>First Name: <?php echo $first_name ?></div>
<div>Last Name: <?php echo $last_name ?></div>
```

Comment: please review the code code i have updated i am having error in this

Comment: humm..I have answered some overview of solving your issue...it should work otherwise..you made some mistakes.. we don't know exactly what you are trying..what is the error..please tell me